# Who knows why I can't plot my chart properly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chart.js

The chart appears but it'completely empty when I change the type to bar, and completely black when I keep horizontalBar.

If I try to cut my data leaving jest few rows the horizontalBar chart appears empty too

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>


</head>
<style>
#wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=javascript>
function makeChart(products)
  

  var Counter = products.map(function(d) {
    return d.Counter;
  });
  var CumVol = products.map(function(d) {
    return +d.CumVol;
  });

  var chart = new Chart('chart', {
    type: "horizontalBar",
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    data: {
      labels: Counter,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: CumVol
        }
      ]
    }
  });
}

// Request data using D3
d3
  .csv("http://localhost:8080/cumvol.csv")
  .then(makeChart);
</SCRIPT>
</body></html>
```

```
Counter;CumVol
1;0.009999999776482582

2;0.029999999329447746

3;0.06999999843537807

4;0.12999999709427357

5;0.13999999687075615

6;0.14999999664723873

7;0.1599999964237213
```

Here few rows of my csv file cumvol

Trying with another file everything is showed properly (I mean changing the name of the columns):

```
Name,Weeks,Gender
Steffi Graf,377,Female
Martina Navratilova,332,Female
Serena Williams,319,Female
Roger Federer,308,Male
Pete Sampras,286,Male
Ivan Lendl,270,Male
Jimmy Connors,268,Male
Chris Evert,260,Female
Novak Djokovic,223,Male
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in the two CSV files, the fields are not separated by the same character (comma vs. semicolon).

You may consider using [d3-csv](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv) instead of [d3.csv](https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/CSV/).

> Please also take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27432751/2358409

Comment: thank you so much, i replaced semicolumns but now I have another issue: it displays data only if I set "line" as type, but I need "bar". For bar the chart loads data and it is 'interactive', but it doesn't show the bars.